# Periodically unable to resolve .local hostname

Tags: networking, server, dns, bonjour

I've got a server on my LAN, let's say it's hostname is `server`.  Periodically I will suddenly be unable to reach the server using `server.local`.  I will get an error which looks like:

```
server.local: Name or service not known
```

This causes various things like ssh and rsync to fail.  In this state I can log in directly to the machine and it has no trouble seeing `server.local`.  I can also connect directly to the machine using its IP address.

If I try nslookup I get this output:

```
nslookup server.local
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find mem.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Isn't ".local" supposed to be running some kind of multicast "bonjour" protocol or something to resolve the address directly without going through a DHCP/DNS server?

Both the client and server are running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Try adding the libnss-resolve package.  18.04 seems to need it.

Comment: @ubfan1 the lookup was already working again by the time you replied, but i have added this package to both systems and will see if the problem shows up again.

Comment: Take a look at bugs 1727237,1805027,1804487 and check dmesg output for NXDOMAIN errors....UDP reduced functionality.  Haven't seen the problem in 20.04 even without the libnss-resolve modifications to /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Comment: @ubfan1 Well it worked for close to a month but suddenly it stopped working again.  I noticed that somehow the machine has lost its IPv4 address...